# Is it good to add regionServer on master node?

Tags: hbase

Such as the title, I only have four machines, so i put the regionServer on the master node.
But, when I write large data to hbase, the master go to hell frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. I personally believe that it is not a good practice to share machines between master and slave daemons in a cluster. HBase applications demand low latency, like tens of milliseconds. If the region server machines are simultaneously using their memory/disk/CPU resources for other stuff, then HBase latency could go up significantly, which will be the case if you are running other daemons like NN, HM, JT, TT and DN on the same machine.

Moreover NN and HM already have high memory consumption, since everything is in-memory. This is the reason why your HM is going down frequently.

Answer (score 0):

in short, Regionserver needs to run on the same server as data nodes - writes going to region server go to memstore from where they are written to HDFS (disk).  First HDFS block replicas go to the local data node and two other writes to other data nodes - resulting in the regionserver (serving the region) getting local access to data (thereby helping in data locality).